# memory copying causes an offset

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, memcpy

It seems memcpy creates an offset in the destination array I am copying the data.
here I generate the source buffer defined in header as:

> ```
> float  segments[360*RANGE_INDEX*6];
> ```

```
void GlWidget::GenerateBuffers()
{
    //    srand( 0 );
    int angleIndex = segmentIndex * 20;

    for(int i = angleIndex; i < angleIndex + 20; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < RANGE_INDEX; j++)
        {
            float randNumber = rand() % 255;

            for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
            {
                segments[(i*RANGE_INDEX+j)*6+k] = randNumber/255.0f;
            }
        }
}
```

I already initialized the source buffer to 0 using iteration.

```
void GlWidget::exec()
{// memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );

    qDebug() << "inside exec()";

    int startIndex;
    int finalIndex;

    startIndex = segmentIndex * 20;
    finalIndex = startIndex + 20;
    ppi->MemCpyToColorVector(&segments[0*RANGE_INDEX], 0);
}
```

Here, I copy the source to destination, the problem I have is for the first i, that is for angle 0, it's ok, the color of every six vertices remains the same (0 to 599). But, for angle 1 (i == 1), the source buffer is correct, the index of 600 to 605 keep the same value, though in the destination buffer, color, 600 and 601 are the same and from 603 it differs.

```
    void PlanPositionIndicator::MemCpyToColorVector(float* segments, int angleIndex)
    {// memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );

   //    QVector<float> colors;

        size_t bytes;

        int index;

        index = 0;

        bytes = 0;

        index = angleIndex * _RANGE_CNT;

        index *= 6;

        bytes = sizeof(float) * _RANGE_CNT * 6;

        memcpy(&colors[index], &segments[index], bytes);
    }
```

is this offset created by memcpy? what is your opinion?

Comment: If you think `memcpy` causes an offset, you could write a far simpler program to test that hypothesis.

Comment: i did it for an array of 18, it's copied every 6 element fine.

Comment: It is quite hard to see what exactly are you doing. For example, the ´color´ variable in the last code snippet. Is it a QVector or something else? In the first code snippet you have 3 nested for loops and from that code alone it is impossible to say what's going on. Depending on the value of `segmentIndex` you might even write outside the array. To me it seems that you are trying to use a too simple data structure (one float array) which causes too complicated code.

Comment: yes, color is a QVector

Comment: What is `_RANGE_CNT`?

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy` is a low-level function. It copies whole pieces of memory from one pointer to another. Using it on complex data structures, like `QVector`, without knowing its internal structure is a simple way to specific errors. If you need to copy data from `float *` to `QVector < float >` you should do simply:

```
if (colors.size() < (index + _RANGE_CNT * 6))
    colors.resize(index + _RANGE_CNT * 6);
for (int i = 0; i < _RANGE_CNT * 6; ++i)
    colors[index + i] = segments[index + i];
```